# Finding the ideal of a variety of a set (example)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From Reid, let $J=\left<XY,XZ,YZ\right>\subset k[X,Y,Z]$. Find $V(J)\subset\mathbb{A}^3(k)$, and find whether it is irreducible. Is it true that $J=I(V(J))$? Prove that $J$ cannot be generated by $2$ elements.

I know how to find $V(J)$ but then how would I find $I(V(J))$ to be able to consider $k[X,Y,Z]/I(V(J))$. Also, how would I approach proving that $J$ cannot be finitely generate by 2 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $V(J)$ is the union of the three axis, and so is reducible. If $f(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial which is zero on all the axis, then consider $f(x,0,0)$. This polynomial is zero for all $x$ and thus is identically equal to zero. Thus $f$ has no pure terms, that is terms $ax^n$ or $ay^n$ etc. And this gives that $f\in J$. To show its not generated by two elements, factor by the ideal of all polynomial of degree $>2$. Then $J$ as a module over this algebra, has zero multiplication by polynomials and as a vector spac over $k$, has dimension $3$, so cannot be generated by $2$ elements.

Comment: @Hurkyl I dont understand your point is $x=y=0$,$z=1$ ?

Comment: @Hurkyl Been there !